# Plucker bilinear product identity

Tags: geometry

In a certain textbook chapter dealing with Plucker product representations of lines in homogeneous coordinates, a certain bilinear form is introduced

$$ (L|\hat{L})=l_{12}\hat{l}_{34}+\hat{l}_{12}l_{34}+ l_{13}\hat{l}_{42}+\hat{l}_{13}l_{42}+ l_{14}\hat{l}_{23}+\hat{l}_{14}l_{23}$$

where $(l_{12}, l_{13},l_{14}, l_{23},l_{42}, l_{34},)$ are the 6 Plucker coordinates of line $L$ and similarly for $\hat{L}$.

It is then claimed, without proof, that if $L$ is the intersection two planes, represented by 4x1 homogeneous vectors P and Q, and  $\hat{L}$ is the join of two points A and B,also represented by 4x1 vectors, then

$$(L|\hat{L})=(P^TA)(Q^TB) - (Q^TA)(P^TB) $$

Can someone give or point me to a proof of the above?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%BCcker_coordinates

Comment: I'm afraid I've already been to the wikipedia page and do not see the identity above discussed.

Comment: yes, but you specified no book either

Comment: Well,the book where I've encountered this is "Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision" by Hartley and Zisserman, but I was hoping that someone might be familiar with the result (and its proof) from other sources. My book is obviously short of information, else I wouldn't need to look elsewhere.

Comment: this one seems approachable http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642309939

Comment: One way to tackle this would be choosing generic coordinates for all the elements involved, i.e. $P=(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)^T$ and so on, then compute $L$ and $\hat L$ from that, then expand both sides of the equation and see that they are the same in terms of all the coordinates. This aproach probably won't give you a lot of structural insight, but it doesn't require much thought either, just some work with a computer algebra system.

Comment: @MvG, thanks. Direct substitution would definitely get the job done. I was hoping for that "structural insight" that you mention, though.

Answer (score -1):

The equation for the bilinear product given in the Hartley and Zisserman text (based on 4 points) was the determinant of a 4x4 matrix, where each column of the matrix represented a point.

First we'll show that the equation given in the text (based on 2 points and 2 planes) is equal to the distance from point B to the plane formed by point A and the line of intersection of planes P and Q, multiplied by the length of the normal vector to the plane formed by A / P / Q.

Second, we'll show that, if each column of a matrix is considered to be a point, the determinant of the matrix is equal to the distance of one of the points to the plane composed of the other points, multiplied by the length of the normal vector to the plane formed by the other points.

Step 1:

line L* = $PQ^T - QP^T$

plane of L* B = $PQ^TB - QP^TB$

distance from A to plane

= $(PQ^TB - QP^TB)^TA / $length of plane normal

= $(B^TQP^TA - B^TPQ^TA) / $length of plane normal

= $((Q^TB)(P^TA) - (P^TB)(Q^TA)) / $length of plane normal

$((Q^TB)(P^TA) - (P^TB)(Q^TA)) = $ (distance from A to plane) * (length of plane normal)

Step 2:

I worked through the algebra for three points in 2D space, it should be similar for four points in 3D space.  For points P0, P1, and P2:

determinant = $x0(y1 - y2) + x1(y2 - y0) + x2(y0 - y1)$

distance from P0 to line P1=>P2 = $(x0(y1 - y2) + x1(y2 - y0) + x2(y0 - y1)) / \sqrt((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2)$

determinant = (distance from P0 to line P1=>P2) * $\sqrt((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2)$

$\sqrt((y2 - y1)^2 + (x2 - x1)^2)$ is the length of the line normal.